# How to vertically auto size a winforms datagridview control, so that its rows are always visible

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that displays a limited number of rows, never more than 5. This `DataGridView`is placed on a `DataRepeater` control so it's usually displayed many times on the screen. What I want to achieve is that all grids are resized to the size of their contents so they don't display scroll bars if 4 or 5 items are in them or take up extra vertical space if only 1 or 2 items are there.

The grids only contain text data. They are data bound controls, so they'll need to resize if the underlying data source changes (I guess the `DataBindingComplete` event would be suitable).

How may I achieve this? Is counting rows the best option? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a more accurate answer [DataGridView Auto Height - How to AutoSize DataGridView Height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816425/datagridview-auto-height-how-to-autosize-datagridview-height)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since your control is data-bound, I would set the `Height` property on the DataGridView to the sum of the heights of its rows (plus some margin) in the `DataBindingComplete` event:

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    var height = 40;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows) {
        height += dr.Height;
    }

    dataGridView1.Height = height;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I took hmqcnoesy's answer and expanded on it and created a function to also include the width. And to use on any grid.

Note: Set AutoSizeCells = AllCells on the grid.

```
    public static DataGridView SetGridHeightWidth(DataGridView grd, int maxHeight, int maxWidth)
    {
        var height = 40;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grd.Rows)
        {
            if(row.Visible)
                height += row.Height;
        }

        if (height > maxHeight)
            height = maxHeight;

        grd.Height = height;

        var width = 60;
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in grd.Columns)
        {
            if (col.Visible)
                width += col.Width;
        }

        if (width > maxWidth)
            width = maxWidth;

        grd.Width = width;

        return grd;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This value can be anything. You should test in your grid to discover what's the best value to set the height.

```
var height = 40;
```

Edited:

To find the real value to height, you need add the **location of grid** and **height of header**. Something like that.

```
int height = dgv.Location.Y + dgv.ColumnHeadersHeight;
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgv.Rows) {
   height += dr.Height; // Row height.
}
dgv.Height = height;
```