# DataGridView Auto Height - How to AutoSize DataGridView Height?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to make the height of my DataGridView AutoSize based on the amount of rows it contains. Currently, I was able to accomplish this with the following line:

```
dataGridView_SearchResults.AutoSize = true;
```

However this makes the Horizontal scroll bar disappear, the the DataGridView gets cut off.

How can I autosize the height without losing the horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: Set its MaximumSize property.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't know what the mistake I'd made when I test for `MaximumSize` which made me sure that it wont work, but reading your comment I gave it another try and it worked. Yes, setting `new Size(this.dataGridView1.Width, 0)` is completely working.

Comment: @HansPassant But since using `MaximumSize`  is not so friendly when the user wants to let the grid width change, I prefer to use *Option 1* or *Option 2* in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1 - Overriding GetPreferredSize**

You can override [`GetPreferredSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.getpreferredsize(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `DataGridView` and call the base method using new proposed size `new Size(this.Width, proposedSize.Height)`. This way, the current width of control will remain untouched while the auto-size rules will apply on its height:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    public override Size GetPreferredSize(Size proposedSize)
    {
        return base.GetPreferredSize(new Size(this.Width, proposedSize.Height));
    }
}
```

**Option 2 - Setting the Height based on Height of Calculated Auto-Size**

If you don't want to derive from `DataGridView`, you can calculate the auto-size by calling its `GetPreferredSize` passing `new Size(0, 0)` then set the height of `DataGridView` to the height of result, this way you only change the height of `DataGridView`. You should set the auto-height in `RowsAdded`, `RowsRemoved`, some other events if you need:

```
void AutoHeightGrid(DataGridView grid)
{
    var proposedSize = grid.GetPreferredSize(new Size(0, 0));
    grid.Height = proposedSize.Height;
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.RowsAdded += (obj, arg) => AutoHeightGrid(dataGridView1);
    dataGridView1.RowsRemoved += (obj, arg) => AutoHeightGrid(dataGridView1);
    //Set data source
    //dataGridView1.DataSource = something;
}
```

If you want to make sure that all changes in grid including changing `Font`, height of rows will cause resizing grid, you can call the method in `Paint` event.

**Option 3 - Setting MaximumSize**

Also as mentioned by Hans, if you don't want to derive from `DataGridView`, you can use `MaximumSize` property of the grid. You can set it  to `new Size(this.dataGridView1.Width, 0)`:

```
dataGridView1.MaximumSize = new Size(this.dataGridView1.Width, 0);
dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;
```

**Note**

Since using `MaximumSize` is not so friendly when the user wants to let the grid width change by left and right anchors, I prefer to use *Option 1* or *Option 2*.

Comment: Do I need to create my own DataGridView class  to accomplish this?

Comment: wow thank you for such a detailed answer. I went with option 2 :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried every option proposed by [Reza Aghaei](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38816736/14653309) using *.NET Framework 4.7.2*. All the times I got an extra space between the last row and the `DataGridView` bottom border. So I tried a different approach, and it works!
Using the event you prefer, write the following line:

```
dataGridView1.Height = DataGridView1.Rows.GetRowsHeight(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)
   + (dataGridView1.ScrollBars.HasFlag(ScrollBars.Horizontal) ? SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight : 0)
   + 3;
```

You'd change the last `+3` according to the style of your choice. Just change it from +1 to +5 depending of your likes.

Answer (score 1):

I modified answer of Jesus by

```
DGV.Height = DGV.Rows.GetRowsHeight(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible) + DGV.ColumnHeadersHeight;
```

I don`t use scroll bar, but you can add it from Jesus answer