# Adjusting TableLayoutPanel Row height when rows added/removed from DataGridView

Tags: winforms, datagridview, tablelayoutpanel

I have a TableLayoutPanel which contains multiple rows, some of which contain TextBox'es and some of which contain DataGridView's. I set the SizeType of TableLayoutPanel rows that contain DataGridView's to AutoSize. I was hoping that as rows are added/removed from the DataGridView's that the height of the rows containing them would increase/decrease. It is not happening. Am I misunderstanding how this should work? Is there a way to get this to work the way I was expecting?

Comment: Try setting `DataGridView.AutoSize = true;` with code (for some reason it's not present in the designer).

Comment: [DataGridView Auto Height - How to AutoSize DataGridView Height?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38816425/3110834)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two commenters were right :) It turns out the issue was with the DataGridView itself. I ended up using [method 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38816736/68936). I built a test app with multiple tabs, each tab containing a datagridview and a button to add rows, and a button to remove rows. The first tab just contained those 3 components, I just wanted to make sure that it could indeed grow. In the second tab I put the 3 components inside a Panel with Autoscroll set to true; that also worked fine. And so on, until I put the datagridview and buttons inside a TableLayoutPanel (also with Autoscroll set to true), inside a user control. It all works fine. Just in case others want to experiment, it made things quicker to just drop 2 buttons and a datagridview on each tab and use the following code (in the main form) to initialize them (rather than using the designer).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Setup(dataGridView1, buttonAddRow1, buttonRemoveRow1);
        Setup(dataGridView2, buttonAddRow2, buttonRemoveRow2);
        Setup(dataGridView3, buttonAddRow3, buttonRemoveRow3);
        Setup(dataGridView4, button1, button2);
        Setup(userControl11.dataGridView4, userControl11.button1, userControl11.button2);

        dataGridView3.MaximumSize = new Size(0, 100);
        dataGridView4.MaximumSize = new Size(0, 100);
    }

    #region static helpers
    private static void Setup(DataGridView grid, Button buttonAdd, Button buttonRemove)
    {
        BindingList<RowItem> list = new BindingList<RowItem>();
        SetupGrid(grid, list);
        buttonAdd.Click += (sender, e) => Add(list);
        buttonRemove.Click += (sender, e) => Remove(list);
    }

    private static void Add(BindingList<RowItem> list)
    {
        list.Add(new RowItem() { Name = "Row " + list.Count });
    }

    private static void Remove(BindingList<RowItem> list)
    {
        if (list.Count > 0)
            list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
    }

    private static void SetupGrid(DataGridView grid, BindingList<RowItem> list)
    {
        grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        grid.RowHeadersVisible = false;        
        grid.Columns.Add(CreateTextColumn("Name"));
        grid.DataSource = list;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets read-only to true
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dataPropertyName"></param>
    /// <param name="format"></param>
    /// <param name="columnName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static public DataGridViewTextBoxColumn CreateTextColumn(string dataPropertyName, string columnName = null, string format = null, bool readOnly = true, DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode autosizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells, int width = 40, DataGridViewColumnSortMode sortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn textColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        textColumn.DataPropertyName = dataPropertyName;
        textColumn.Name = String.IsNullOrEmpty(columnName) ? dataPropertyName : columnName;
        textColumn.ReadOnly = readOnly;
        textColumn.AutoSizeMode = autosizeMode;
        textColumn.Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.True;
        textColumn.Width = width;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(format))
            textColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Format = format;
        textColumn.SortMode = sortMode;
        return textColumn;
    }
    #endregion static helpers
}

class RowItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```