# DataGridView subclassing: change the client area size

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I created a subclass of DataGridView and I'm trying to trick the original Paint function into thinking that the area occupied by rows is higher.

This is how a form looks if there is enough space for all rows:

[image]

in this case scroll bars are not displayed.

I'm trying to achieve this (image manually edited with paint):

[image]

This would give me some blank space below the last row that I can use to paint something.
In this example I supposed that my extra rectangle is about 3 rows high.

I tried to pass OnPaint a new argument with a different clipRect (`MyBase.OnPaint(New PaintEventArgs(e.Graphics, New Rectangle(0, 0, 2000, 2000)))`) but it did not work.

Comment: As an option, you can put an [auto-height DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38816736/3110834) inside an auto-size panel as the container, along with a bit of extra space (maybe another panel docked to bottom) inside the container.

Comment: Thank you Reza, but this would be the outside grid, while I need to draw the extra content within the rows space.

Comment: As far as I see, you don't need t draw within the row, you need to draw on the space below the last row, and as long as the grid is auto-height, inside an auto-scroll container, it doesn't matter the space belongs to the grid or to the container. Well, I'm not claiming this as the cleanest way, just shared the idea, you may find it useful if you didn't find a better approach :)

Comment: In case you find it simpler to managed, you can dock a Control (a Panel, maybe) to Bottom and add it to the DGV Controls collection before setting the DGV's DataSource: it will create an unfilled area at the bottom of the DGV, while the scrollbars work as usual to scroll the Rows/Columns (the vertical Scrollbar will be set on top of the Panel). You can also do the same to dock another Control to the right side (same consideration for the Scrollbar). Then you can paint / add whatever you want to these docked Controls.